# Ошибка Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero in

Tags: php, sql

Подскажите что не то в коде, версия PHP 8..

```
<?php echo $item['va']/$item['vo'];?>
```

Выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero in
```

Comment: `$item['vo'];` у вас либо не сущестует, либо равен нулю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На ноль делить нельзя.

Даже в php :-)

Прежде чем делить, проверьте, что значение не равно нулю

```php
<?php 
if(array_key_exists('vo', $item) && ($item['vo'] != 0)) {
    echo $item['va']/$item['vo'];
}
?>
```

Comment: тогда уж `$vo = (int) $item['vo'] ?? null;` вдруг там стринг придет

Comment: @ВадимАлександру  я хотел привести и `intval` вставить, но потом подумал что там и с плавающей точкой может быть что-то. `$item['vo']` один буй автоматически будет приведет к числу - поэтому не стал заморачиваться. Чуть позже напишу заметку в ответе более общую